# Catching/viewing the http POST from Salesforce Apex Callout

Tags: c#, .net, salesforce, apex, callout

Following this [post](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/03/16/restful-web-service-callout-using-post/) I'm trying to create an Apex Callout from Salesforce to a webservice (.Net) - or something that can receieve the POST.

Being *new to this* I'm uncertain of how to catch the Http `POST` sent from Salesforce. That is I have an Apex Class in Salesforce that gets triggered on **Account** insert:

```
public class WebServiceCallout {

    @future (callout=true)
    public static void sendNotification(String name) {

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();

        req.setEndpoint('http://localhost');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setBody('name='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(name, 'UTF-8'));
        req.setCompressed(true); // otherwise we hit a limit of 32000

        try {
            res = http.send(req);
        } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
            System.debug(res.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

Logically the `req.setEndpoint('http://localhost');` should be replaced with my IP and an acceptable [port](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=configuring_remoteproxy.htm&language=en).

If I wanted to catch this `POST` what project would need to be built in Visual Studio (.Net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a public IP address that isn't going to change and the port isn't blocked by a firewall etc...

Add the IP address to the [Remote Site Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=configuring_remoteproxy.htm&language=en) in Salesforce. This will allow the callout to be made you your endpoint.

You have a very wide range of options in .NET for how to handle an inbound HTTP request. Are you going to host this in IIS, or do you just want something running at the command line with a port open?

It could be as simple as a Web Application that examines the HTTP Request and reads the name from the body.

Comment: For anyone interested I went with the WCF RESTful web service approach that is (for now) hosted/run by a Console Application